# Redux: Make http call ONLY IF data not available in store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I do not want to make an http call unless it is actually required:

This is a workaround I have come up with, *I am checking the state before making http call*

```js
export const fetchOneApi = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const docDetails = getState().DocState;

  // tricking redux to not send http request unless actually required
  if (docDetails.docList[id]) {
    return dispatch({
      type: FETCH_DOC_SUCCESS,
      payload: docDetails.docList[id],
    });
  }

  try {
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_DOC_REQUEST,
    });
    const { data } = await api.get(`/api/${id}`);
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_DOC_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_DOC_FAIL,
      payload: error.error,
    });
  }
};
```

Wondering if there is some redux hook or feature that takes care of this OR atleast a better approach.

Comment: Maybe you can try to create your own custom middleware. https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#middleware

Comment: I do this all the time and I can share some code with you, though it's probably excessively complicated.  I have done this in the past with redux-saga but now I use custom hooks.

Comment: In one implementation I used a hook and I stored the `isLoading` and `error` in the hook itself with `useState` rather than dispatching that info to redux.  In another I have a `meta` for each entity in the redux state with `isLoading`, `error`, `receivedAt`, etc.  In that case, I have a `shouldFetch` selector that makes sure it isn't already loading before starting the dispatch.  So some of it might depend on your reducer.  You would want to make sure that dispatching `FETCH_DOC_REQUEST` will cause `docDetails.docList[id]` to become `true` if you want to prevent duplicate fetch calls.

Comment: I don't see that happening because there is no `id` payload on the `FETCH_DOC_REQUEST` action so you don't know which documents you are requesting.

Answer (score 2):

I've written multiple different custom versions of this functionality for various projects.  I toyed with sharing some examples but it's all excessively complicated since I really love to abstract things.

Based on your question, what you are asking for is the [`createAysncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) function from `redux-toolkit`.  This function creates an action creator which handles dispatching the `pending`, `fulfilled`, and `rejected` actions at the appropriate times.

There are many ways to customize the behavior of the async thunk.  Conditional fetching is described in the docs section ["Cancelling Before Execution"](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#canceling-before-execution):

> If you need to cancel a thunk before the payload creator is called, you may provide a `condition` callback as an option after the payload creator. The callback will receive the thunk argument and an object with `{getState, extra}` as parameters, and use those to decide whether to continue or not. If the execution should be canceled, the `condition` callback should return a literal `false` value:

```
const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/fetchByIdStatus',
  async (userId, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await userAPI.fetchById(userId)
    return response.data
  },
  {
    condition: (userId, { getState, extra }) => {
      const { users } = getState()
      const fetchStatus = users.requests[userId]
      if (fetchStatus === 'fulfilled' || fetchStatus === 'loading') {
        // Already fetched or in progress, don't need to re-fetch
        return false
      }
    }
  }
)
```

In your example you are short-circuiting by dispatching a success action with redundant data. The standard behavior for the above code is that no action will be dispatched at all if the fetch condition returns `false`, which is what we want.

We want to store the `pending` state in redux in order to prevent duplicate fetches.  To do that, your reducer needs to respond to the `pending` action dispatched by the thunk.  You can find out which document was requested by looking at the `action.meta.arg` property.

```
// example pending action from fetchUserById(5)
{
  type: "users/fetchByIdStatus/pending",
  meta: {
    arg: 5, // the userId argument
    requestId: "IjNY1OXk4APoVdaYIF8_I",
    requestStatus: "pending"
  }
}
```

That property exists on [all three of the dispatched actions](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#promise-lifecycle-actions) and its value is the argument that you provide when you call your action creator function.  In the above example it is the `userId` which is presumably a `string` or `number`, but you can use a keyed object if you need to pass multiple arguments.

Comment: Thank mate,  I like it, I wonder why redux not support this one by default, isn't it very easy to implement?

Comment: @TienDang This is an old answer but they do support this now with [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview)